# How do I make a 'while' loop print the results of the loop's conditional into a single line(concatenated)?

Tags: python, while-loop

So here is my code:

```
test = {
    'a':1, 'b':2 , 'c':3 , 'd':4
}

x = raw_input("Type 'abcd' ")
y = len(x)
z = 1
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    print test[a]
    z = z + 1
```

The point is to make a basic encoder, obviously this code is just to establish a quasi-code that I can build off of. My issue is this:

I can't make the result of the 'while' loop print into a single line, and with that, not only print into a single line, but to concatenate into a larger integer(or string for that matter, say the result of the code displayed letters instead of integers, to create a string from those letters). Although, in this code specifically, I want the result of the code to be the integer '**1234**'. Not:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Essentially, my question is this: How do I make the results of a while loop print in such a way that they concatenate integers(or letters) to create a larger number(or string)? I don't want the result
    1
    2
    3
    4

to become 10, but instead I want it to become the integer **1234**. I've looked online, but I can't find anything that works for me. In fact I haven't found anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, using a `while` loop here isn't optimal, instead, use a `for` loop, which is designed to loop over iterators like data structures (a string is just a sequence of characters):

```
for character in x:
    print(test[character])
```

Then instead of printing the characters, store them in a list.

```
characters = []
for character in x:
    characters.append(str(test[character]))
```

We can then join those into a single string (we made the numbers strings earlier to make this step easier), and make an `int` from that string:

```
int("".join(characters))
```

Python supports an easier way to do this kind of list construction - the [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
characters = [str(test[character]) for character in x]
```

This produces the same list as the for loop above, but faster and more concisely.

This means we can write your program as:

```
test = {'a': 1, 'b': 2 , 'c': 3 , 'd': 4}

user_input = raw_input("Type 'abcd':")

number = int("".join(str(test[character]) for character in user_input))
```

As an alternative to making the numbers strings to concatenate, then reverting back, we could also do it with maths:

```
number = sum((10 ** power) * test[character] 
             for power, character in enumerate(reversed(user_input)))
```

What we do here is start from the right, take each number, multiply it up by the power of ten for the column it is in, and then sum the lot.

Comment: +1 for explaining why and how to avoid the `while` loop. Really, if he wants an integer as claimed, I think it's better to build the integer, instead of building a string out of a bunch of integers and then converted it back… But if he does want a string, this is the best way to do it, without all the extraneous stuff I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is: don't print within the `while` loop, but concatenate up a string to print at the end:

```
result = ''
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    result += str(test[a])
    z = z + 1
print result
```

If there are going to be a whole bunch of things, instead of concatenating strings on the fly, use a `list` and `join` at the end:

```
result = []
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    result.append(str(test[a]))
    z = z + 1
print ''.join(result)
```

But you say you want to get an integer. Do you need that integer, for any reason other than to print it out? If so, you *could* build up a string and then convert it to an integer:

```
result = []
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    result.append(str(test[a]))
    z = z + 1
val = int(''.join(result))
```

But this is silly. Why not just build up the value as an integer in the first place?

```
val = 0
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    val = val * 10 + test[a]
    z = z + 1
```

Since you seem to be using Python 2, the only way to print without adding a newline, instead adds a space, which doesn't help. But Python 3—and Python 2 with `from __future__ import print_function`—has a more flexible alternative:

```
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    print(test[a], end='')
    z = z + 1
print()
```

Or you can `write` directly to `stdout`:

```
while z < y+1:
    a = x[z-1]
    sys.stdout.write(str(test[a]))
    z = z + 1
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: I get an error.
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects. 
I think this is because result = a blank string, and test[a] is an integer

Comment: @01110100: Yes, if `test[a]` is an integer… let me adjust the answer.